# Prove that $f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x}{x-4}, & x\not= 4 \\ 0, & x=4 \end{cases}$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Prove that the function $f(x)$ defined by
>   $$
> f(x)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{x}{x-4}, & x\not= 4 \\ 0, & x=4 \end{cases}
> $$
>   is continuous.

My question is: Do I have to prove the two sides limits are equal and thus continuous at the origin? Or just in general it's continuous?

Comment: "codes not equal"?

Comment: The only problem is that $x/(x-4)$ does not have a limit as $x \to 4$, so the indicated function cannot be continuous...

Answer (score 5):

The given function is not continuous at $x=4$ since the limit at that point does not exist.

$$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{x}{x-4} = \frac{4}{0} \,\text{form}$$

Hence the limit above is indeterminate and does not exist.

But $f(4)=0$ is given.

So *the function is continuous at all points in the real axis except at $x=4$* where there is a [essential discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Essential_discontinuity) or, discontinuity of second kind.

Comment: It's not a 0/0 form, it's a 4/0 form.

Comment: @Bungo Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: So, why is L'Hospital's rule applicable? Also, doesn't your second line, which asserts that the limit is $1$, contradict your first sentence, which says it doesn't exist?

Comment: @Bungo It's not applicable, you're right. I was correcting my answer after your first comment when you posted your second comment. Thanks for helping.

Comment: It's actually not a jump discontinuity, the limit is $+\infty$ if $x \to 4$ from the right, and $-\infty$ if $x \to 4$ from the left. If we introduce a change of variable, $y= x-4$, then $x/(x-4)$ becomes $1 + 4/y$. So the function blows up like $1/y$.

Comment: @Bungo Is it okay now?

Comment: The terminology I would use is that there is a pole at $x=4$, but this might be equivalent to "discontinuity of the second kind" - I'm not sure about the definition of the latter.

Comment: @Bungo Discontinuity of the second kind refers to non-removable discontinuity where no matter what value the function assumes at the point of discontinuity, the function is always discontinuous at that point due to the nature of the function..

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for all $x \neq 4$ we have
$$\frac{x}{x-4} = \frac{x-4+4}{x-4} = 1 + \frac{4}{x-4}$$
from which it is clear that
$$\lim_{x \to 4^+}f(x) = +\infty$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to 4^-}f(x) = -\infty$$
hence $f$ cannot be continuous at $x=4$, no matter how we define $f(4)$.